# How can i directly go in the about section of my website if i clicks on about button in header?

Tags: html

How can i directly go in the about section of my website if i clicks on about button in header? I'm a beginner and making my own website by the help of html, CSS and js. I've created my header and all the buttons in it like about, services, contacts us etc. I just want that if i click on any of these buttons in header then i go directly on that section. Suppose if i click on about section in header then how can i go directly on that section.
Which property i should use for making it possible.

Comment: What you looking for is anchor link. Have a look https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/link/html-anchor-link.html

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<a href="your link goes here">About</a>
```

For more details [click/visit here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

Answer (score -1):

```
<button onclick="gotoabout()"></button>
<script>
function gotoabout() {
location.replace(" writ your ABOUT url or directory here ");
}
</script>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
first you try with this example

```
<button onclick="gotoabout()"></button>
<script>
function gotoabout() {
location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66865048/how-can-i-directly-go-in-the-about-section-of-my-website-if-i-clicks-on-about-bu");
}
```